# Force RSS feed title to change in user's reader

Tags: rss

I make a mistake of leaving the title of a RSS feed empty when I publish it. So the feed title appear as "title unknown" in RSS readers when people subscribe to it.Now that the title has been added in, is there a way to forces the feed title in the end user's RSS feed reader (ie. Google Reader)?

Comment: RSS is a text file. How are you generating  it ? Some clients will reload title information from time to time, others will never change it after the user has subscribed to your feed.

Answer (score 0):

As koan already said, some RSS-Readers might never check for this again and other might do it every time they fetch your RSS-Feed for new updates.

Although, RSS offers you the `<ttl>`-sub-element for the `<channel>`-element, which is:

> a number of minutes that indicates how long a channel can be cached
>   before refreshing from the source.

(see the [RSS-specs](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltttlgtSubelementOfLtchannelgt)).

The docs however do not give any idea about how this "refreshing" has to look, so some RSS-Readers might only reload the items and some might even ignore it.

It's a good idea to use the [`<pubDate>` and `<lastBuildDate>`](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#optionalChannelElements) elements which might also have an impact on how and if the contents are reloaded. If you use a script to create your RSS-Feed, this might be implemented already.

Also, users which previously subscribed to your RSS-Feed might already have changed the title on the Reader manually, so adding a `<title>`-element only has an impact on new subscribers.